# Bootstrap Carousel in Foreach Loop

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, foreach

I have Carousel with 4 images like given in the following image.

[image]

My Effort is given in following.

```
<div id="thumbCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php $i=0; foreach($this->partner_images as $sr){?>
             <?php if($i==0){ ?><div class="item active"><?php } ?>
                 <?php if($i ==4){ ?><div class="item"><?php }?>
                      <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <a href="<?php echo $sr['url']; ?>">
   <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/partner-images/<?php echo $sr['name']?>" />
                            </a>
                      </div>
                            <?php if($i==3 or $i==7){ ?></div><?php }?>
                          <?php $i++; } ?>
                     </div>
                    <a class="thumbleft" href="#thumbCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                    <a class="thumbright" href="#thumbCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that it is working fine for 4 images and for 8 images, so when there are 4 or more picture are not showing properly. I want to do it automatically either images are even or odd.

**Question:**
My question is how i can show 4 or more images like shown in the images automatically ?

Comment: Why not use `% (MOD)`

Comment: @AliZia how i can use % please explain.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I try this and it is working fine.**

```
<div id="thumbCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php $i=0; foreach($this->partner_images as $sr){?>
         <?php if($i==0){ ?><div class="item active"><?php } ?>
             <?php if($i % 2 == 0){ ?><div class="item"><?php }?>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <a href="<?php echo $sr['url']; ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/partner-images/<?php echo $sr['name']?>" />
                        </a>
                  </div>
                        <?php if($i % 4 != 0){ ?></div><?php }?>
                      <?php $i++; } ?>
                 </div>
                <a class="thumbleft" href="#thumbCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                <a class="thumbright" href="#thumbCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a>
     </div>
</div>
```